# Why isn't the data from the input file transferred? Django

Tags: python, html, django, input

I want to check the data I received from the request, but the data in the input(file multiple = "True")tag is not transferred.

```
<form>
  ...
  <input type="file" name="img_section_1" multiple>
  ...
<form>
```

```
print(request.FILES.get('img_section_1'))
>>>None
```

I dont want to form field. Because i cann't expect how many inputs i will recieve

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: If you are uploading files, you MUST use `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`.  The default encoding doesn't handle files.